# free memory allocation after malloc

Tags: c, malloc, free

I was reading the "c primer plus" by Stephen Prata. There is sample program for linked list. The program uses malloc to allocate the memory space for a structure array, the code for the sample program is as below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define TSIZE 45

struct film{
 char title[TSIZE];
 int rating;
 struct film * next;
 };
char * s_gets(char * st,int n);

int main(void)
{
  struct film * head =NULL;
  struct film * prev, * current;
  char input[TSIZE];

puts("Enter first movie title:");
while(s_gets(input,TSIZE)!=NULL && input[0]!='\0')
{
    current=(struct film *)malloc(sizeof(struct film));
    if(head==NULL)
        head=current;
    else
        prev->next=current;
    current->next=NULL;
    strcpy(current->title,input);
    puts("Enter your rating <0-10>:");
    scanf("%d",&current->rating);
    while(getchar()!='\n')
        continue;
    puts("Enter next movie title (empty line to stop):");
    prev=current;
}
if(head==NULL)
    printf("No data entered.\n");
else
    printf("Here is the movie list:\n");
current=head;
while(current!=NULL)
{
    printf("Movie: %s Rating: %d\n",current->title,current->rating);

    current=current->next;
}
current=head;
while(current!=NULL)
{
    free(current);
    current=current->next;
}
printf("Bye!\n");

return 0;
}

char * s_gets(char * st,int n)
{
char * ret_val;
char * find;
if((ret_val=fgets(st,n,stdin)))
{
    if((find=strchr(st,'\n'))!=NULL)
    *find='\0';
    else
        while(getchar()!='\n')
        continue;
}
return ret_val;
}
```

My confusion is from the memory free code. The current is freed by 
     `free(current);`
why the following line can get effect? `current=current->next;` since current is freed, this line should have no way to access the current memeber "next".

Looking forward to your help on this.

Thanks so much.

Comment: This is a bad code. It cannot work. If this is coming from a book - trash it and get a better one.

Comment: That is a dead loop, the previous loop makes sure `current == NULL` already!!

Comment: @SouravGhosh Looks like the OP have messed with the original code. I found the code online and it has `current=head;` before the second loop. But the `free` bug is still there.

Comment: You just got yourself a bad book (one of he many!). You can browse the good books list here: https://web.archive.org/web/20171226004830/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list (this was a Stack Overflow post, which recently was deleted for unclear reasons).

Comment: It is really bothering me that this (and similar) book is getting 5 star rating in online stores.

Comment: @SergeyA https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355588/the-c-book-list-has-gone-haywire-what-to-do-with-it

Comment: Sorry, i missed the current=head before the loop to free memory. A type error.

Comment: actually this book is a very famous book for c. I am very close to the end of the book, this is the only one bug i found in the book. Thanks so much for your reply, it really help me a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do this

```
while(current!=NULL)
{
    free(current);
    current=current->next;
}
```

You make `current` pointer dangling and you try to access it `current=current->next;` which will result in undefined behavior.

I would suggest you to free as below.
Also Your `current` pointer will be pointing to `NULL` since you have looped till end of the list before to the free while loop.

```
current=head;
while(current!=NULL)
{
    struct film * temp = current;
    current=current->next;
    free(temp);
}
```

Comment: This modification can fix the bug. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score -2):

The
free(current); 
does not clean any of the memory which is at the @ of current, just give it back to the memory pool, so it can be reuse, no cleanning of the memory is done, so it will continue to contain the same data
better practive would be to add
current=NULL; 
just after

Comment: Ok, i got your point. It means, without free operation, if you assign any other value to the location, there will be a fatal error and program interrupt. With a free operation, the memory can used to store other things. Thanks so much for your kindly reply.